# Is there any way to convert .DOCX file to PDF vai using Apache POI and Itext

Tags: java, apache-poi, itext

I have following concern while converting docx to pdf with using Apache POI and Itext.

1. While converting docx to pdf, special character are getting missed and not able to read Numbering Format from docx.
2. Images are not in sync in converted format(which is PDF)

Is there any way to do all these. I am forced to do with these 2 APIs only.
Please suggest.

Comment: Please show us your code!

Comment: Regarding 1: POI doesn't compute NumberTexts of lists automatically. However, TIKA does. / Can you provide a sample file exhibiting the "special character" issue in [POI's Bugtracker](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?product=POI)?